# Reference to a class library (.Net framework) method from .Net core API is throwing an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cryptography, asp.net-core-webapi, class-library

I have a Web API project whose target framework is `.Net Core 2.1`. The project has reference to a class library built on **.Net Framework 4.5.2**.  While calling the method on the class library which basically encodes / decodes a given value is throwing the following run time error.

> Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.MACTripleDES' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.":"System.Security.Cryptography.MACTripleDES"

Method defined on class Library:

```
    public string Encryptor(string ID)
    {
        string EncrytionKey = "sampleKey";
        MACTripleDES mac3des = new MACTripleDES();
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        mac3des.Key = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(EncrytionKey));

        return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ID)) + '-' + Convert.ToBase64String(mac3des.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ID)));

    }
```

I could see similar questions on SO, suggesting to add **project.json** file to the project but I am not clear. Neither my Web API nor class library has a **project.json** file in it.

Please provide any insights on it.

Comment: `MACTripleDES` simply doesn't exist for .NET core

Comment: Did you find any solution of this @Sreekanth , as i am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me seems to be:

1. Upgrading the MACTripleDES version: NuGet package.config file:
2. Provide assembly binding redirects: 
      `<dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Cryptography.MACTripleDES" 
          publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0"
           newVersion="4.0.2.0" /> 
        </dependentAssembly>

       <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Cryptography.MACTripleDES"

           publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0"
          newVersion="4.3.0.0" /> 
       </dependentAssembly>`

Comment: I couldn't find a nuget package with that name. Do you mean adding those binding redirects changes to my app.config file and install nuget package in web api project?

Comment: check this link to get more information about yout problem [.NET API](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Security.Cryptography)